# Call a specific gem helper inside a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imgix

I need to use the [imgix-rails](https://github.com/imgix/imgix-rails) gem inside a project.

I need to call an helper inside a model, this helper:

```
require "imgix"
require "imgix/rails/tag"
require "imgix/rails/image_tag"
require "imgix/rails/picture_tag"

module Imgix
  module Rails
    module ViewHelper
      include UrlHelper

      def ix_image_tag(source=nil, path, tag_options: {}, url_params: {}, srcset_options: {})
        return Imgix::Rails::ImageTag.new(path, source: source, tag_options: tag_options, url_params: url_params, srcset_options: srcset_options).render
      end

      def ix_picture_tag(source=nil, path, tag_options: {}, url_params: {}, breakpoints: {}, srcset_options: {})
        return Imgix::Rails::PictureTag.new(path, source: source, tag_options: tag_options, url_params: url_params, breakpoints: breakpoints, srcset_options: srcset_options).render
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I cannot find a way to call `ix_image_tag`.

Comment: Did you try `include Imgix::Rails::ViewHelper` in your model?

Comment: What's the specific use you're giving to that gem and what Rails version are you using?